# Как остановить текущую задачу Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

В общем и целом, такая задумка. На странице есть форма и зелёная кнопка "Запустить". При нажатии на эту кнопку должно происходить следующее:

1. форма сохраняется;
2. зеленая кнопка "Запустить" меняется на красную кнопку "Остановить";
3. вызывается функция из views.py, которая выполняется на фоне, с помощью Celery;

   При нажатии на красную кнопку "Остановить" должно происходить следующее:
4. красная кнопка меняется на зелёную;
5. задача, которая выполнялась на фоне должна остановиться;

Сделал всё, кроме последнего пункта.
Кнопки меняю с помощью глобальной булевой переменной, которую проверяю в шаблоне. Понимаю, что код мой очень сильно корявый, но этой мой первый практический опыт, так что сильно не осуждайте(

Знаю, что задачу можно остановить методом abort(), но не могу понять, как получить активную задачу, чтобы применить этот метод. Пытался получить её методом inspect, ноо дальше что делать я не знаю...
Подскажите пожалуйста, что тут можно сделать

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import *
from django.views.generic import DetailView, FormView
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from instabot import Bot
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .tasks import *
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import time
from instaPrime import celery_app


process = False


class Settings(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    model = InstAcc
    form_class = FormSettingAcc
    template_name = 'primeApp/settings.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        source = SettingAcc.objects.get(account=InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user))
        form = FormSettingAcc(request.POST or None, instance=source)
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save()
            new_form.account = InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user)
            new_form.save()

            if request.POST.get('stop'):
                print('stop')
                i = celery_app.control.inspect()
                apps = i.active()
                # тут не знаю что придумать

                global process
                process = False

            else:
                print('start')
                start(request)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['account'] = InstAcc.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        source = SettingAcc.objects.get(account=InstAcc.objects.get(user=self.request.user))
        context['form'] = FormSettingAcc(self.request.POST or None, instance=source)
        context['process'] = process
        return context



def start(request):
    global process
    process = True

    account = InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user)
    setting = SettingAcc.objects.get(account=InstAcc.objects.get(user=request.user))
    options = {"liking": setting.liking,
               "following": setting.following,
               "unfollowing": setting.unfollowing,
               "hashtag":  setting.hashtag,
               "competitors": setting.competitors,
               "list": setting.list}
    process = action.delay(account.login_inst, account.password_inst, options)
    return
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task
from instabot import Bot
from .models import *
from instaPrime.celery import app
import random
from celery.contrib.abortable import AbortableTask


@app.task(bind=True, base=AbortableTask)
def action(self, login, password, options):
    bot = Bot(max_likes_to_like=100,
              max_followers_to_follow=2000,
              min_followers_to_follow=40,
              max_following_to_follow=10000,
              min_following_to_follow=10,
              max_followers_to_following_ratio=10,
              max_following_to_followers_ratio=2,
              min_media_count_to_follow=3,
              stop_words=['shop', 'store', 'free'],
              follow_delay=30,
              like_delay=10,
              unfollow_delay=30)
    bot.login(username=login, password=password, is_threaded=True, force=True)

    count_media_likes = 2
    list = options["list"].split()
    user_medias_id = []
    media_likers = []

    for competitor in list:
        user_medias_id.append(bot.get_user_medias(user_id=competitor, filtration=False)[0:len(list)*2])

    for medias in user_medias_id:
        for media in medias:
            media_likers.append(bot.get_media_likers(media)[0:100])

    pers = []
    for persons in media_likers:
        for person in persons:
            pers.append(person)

    if options["competitors"]:
        if options["following"] and options["liking"]:
            for liker in pers:

                if self.is_aborted():
                    print('abort')
                    return False

                bot.follow(liker)
                print('Подписка на ', bot.get_username_from_user_id(liker))
                medias = bot.get_user_medias(user_id=liker, filtration=False)
                try:
                    if len(medias) < count_media_likes:
                        print('Лайк не поставился (мало публикаций в профиле)')
                    else:
                        for i in range(count_media_likes):
                            k = random.randint(0, len(medias))
                            bot.like(medias[k])
                            print('Лайкаем ', medias[k])
                except:
                    print('Лайк не поставился :(')

    return False
```

**Шаблон (а конкретно форма)**

```
<form method="post" action="">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="options-wrapper">
            <h4>Действия</h4>
            <div class="options-action">
              <label class="checkbox-img" >
                {{ form.liking }}<span></span>
              </label>

              <label class="checkbox-img">
                {{ form.following }}<span></span>
              </label>

              <label class="checkbox-img">
                {{ form.unfollowing }}<span></span>
              </label>
            </div>

            <h4>Способ продвижения</h4>
            <div class="options-action">
              <label class="checkbox-img">
                {{ form.hashtag }}<span></span>
              </label>

              <label class="checkbox-img">
                {{ form.competitors }}<span></span>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">@</span>
              </div>
              {{ form.list }}
            </div>

            {% if process %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger start mt-3" value="Остановить" id="stop" name="stop">
            {% else %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success start mt-3" value="Запустить" id="start">
            {% endif %}



          </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

создал глобальную переменную process_id, и в функции start() после начала фоновой задачи, присвоил этой переменной id задачи

```
process = action.delay(account.login_inst, account.password_inst, options)
process_id = process.id
```

И далее, при нажатии на кнопку "Остановить", использовал revoke, куда передавал глобальную переменную process_id

```
 if request.POST.get('stop'):
      print('stop')
      celery_app.control.revoke(process_id, terminate=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помог!